# Can a QGIS project file (qgz) be used by several users at the same time?

Tags: qgis, qgz

I am wondering whether a QGIS project file (qgz) can be used by several users at the same time? I can't test it at the moment thats why I ask.

Comment: Yes. Though changes comitted by one user wont be visible to the others, and only the last changes comitted will be available later on.